# Here is the code for adding an extra combobox item, but the respective comboboxes value is not changing

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, combobox, addition

It is not changing the corresponding combobox value why it is changing the latest combobox value not the respective combobox?

When i run this code, after clicking addfield two times, when i change the first combobox the second combobox value should change not the fourth combobox, this is wrong, what i want is depending on first combobox selection second combobox should be selectable and if third combobox is selected, then the fourth combobox should be selectable.

add Field button adds extra comboboxes in the window, the way it should work is, in the case when the add Field button is pressed twice, i select first combobox, respectively second combobox should be selectable but for some reason, fourth combobox is getting selectable. you will understand the problem better when you run the above code, I have provided the entire code in the description, please help!

```
package addextraitem;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ExtraComboBox {

    int count = 0;
    JComboBox fruits[] = new JComboBox[10];;
    JPanel comboPanel;
    JFrame guiFrame;
    //JComboBox dude1;
    String[] valOptions3 = {"&"};
    String[] valOptions2 = {"|->", "|=>"};
    String[] valOptions1 = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
    String[] valOptions0 = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
    String[] fruitOptions1 = {"", "Delay1", "Delay2", "Delay3"};
    String chosenString;
    int numPairs1 = valOptions0.length;
    JButton addField;
    int count1 = 0;
    JComboBox[] ComboBox4 = new JComboBox[numPairs1];
    JComboBox[] ComboBox5 = new JComboBox[numPairs1];
    JComboBox[] ComboBox6 = new JComboBox[numPairs1];
    String[] comborel = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    JLabel lb;
    JComboBox dude;
    JTextField handle;
    String clockOptions1;
    JLabel dudel[] = new JLabel[10];
    JComboBox dude1[] = new JComboBox[10];
    JComboBox dude2[] = new JComboBox[10];;
    //JComboBox dude1[] = new JComboBox[10];
    String[] valOptions = {"Unknown", "0", "1"};
    String [] s = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"};
    int cnt = 0;
    int i = 0;
    JLabel comboLbl;
    JLabel lb1;
    //Note: Typically the main method will be in a
    //separate class. As this is a simple one class
    //example it's all in the one class.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ExtraComboBox();
    }

    public ExtraComboBox()
    {
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        //make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("ComboBox GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(350,250);

        //This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //The first JPanel contains a JLabel and JCombobox
        comboPanel = new JPanel();

        addField = new JButton("Add Field");
        addField.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if (event.getSource() == addField) {
                    count1++;
                    comboLbl = new JLabel("Select a relation:");
                    fruits[count1] = new JComboBox(fruitOptions1);
                    MyItemListener2 actionListener2 = new MyItemListener2();
                    fruits[count1].addItemListener(actionListener2);
                    //System.out.println("HI: " + fruits[count1].getParent());
                    dude2[count1] = new JComboBox();
                    System.out.println("ADD FIELDS: " + count1);
                    comboPanel.add(comboLbl);
                    comboPanel.add(fruits[count1]);
                    comboPanel.add(dude2[count1]);
                    guiFrame.revalidate();
                    guiFrame.validate();
                    guiFrame.pack();
                    guiFrame.repaint();
                }
            }
        });

        comboPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(comboPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        comboPanel.add(addField);                
        //The JFrame uses the BorderLayout layout manager.
        //Put the two JPanels and JButton in different areas.
        guiFrame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);        
        //make sure the JFrame is visible
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyItemListener2 implements ItemListener {
        // This method is called only if a new item has been selected.
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox) evt.getSource();

        Object item = evt.getItem();

        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            // Item was just selected
            System.out.println("COUNTER: " + count1);
            System.out.println(evt.getItem());

            dude2[count1].removeAllItems();

            if(evt.getItem() == "Delay1") {
                System.out.println(valOptions1.length);
                for(int i = 0; i < valOptions1.length; i++) {
                    dude2[count1].addItem(valOptions1[i]); //dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                    System.out.println(valOptions1[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(evt.getItem() == "Delay2") {
                System.out.println(valOptions2.length);
                for(int j = 0; j < valOptions2.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(valOptions2[j]);
                    dude2[count1].addItem(valOptions2[j]); //dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                }
            }
            else if(evt.getItem() == "Delay3") {
                System.out.println(valOptions3.length);
                for(int j = 0; j < valOptions3.length; j++) {
                    System.out.println(valOptions3[j]);
                    dude2[count1].addItem(valOptions3[j]); //dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                }
            }
        } else if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
            // Item is no longer selected
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ExtraComboBox {
    private int maxFields = 4; // The max number of fields allowed in the dialog
    JComboBox fruits[] = new JComboBox[maxFields];
    JPanel comboPanel;
    JFrame guiFrame;
    String[] valOptions3 = { "&" };
    String[] valOptions2 = { "|->", "|=>" };
    String[] valOptions1 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    String[] valOptions0 = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
    String[] fruitOptions1 = { "", "Delay1", "Delay2", "Delay3" };
    JButton addField;
    int count1 = 0;

    JLabel dudel[] = new JLabel[maxFields];
    JComboBox dude2[] = new JComboBox[maxFields];
    String[] valOptions = { "Unknown", "0", "1" };
    String[] s = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
    private JLabel comboLbl;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExtraComboBox();
    }

    public ExtraComboBox() {
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        // make sure the program exits when the frame closes
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("ComboBox GUI");
        guiFrame.setSize(350, 350);

        // The first JPanel contains a JLabel and JCombobox
        comboPanel = new JPanel();

        addField = new JButton("Add Field");
        addField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (event.getSource().equals(addField)) {
                    if (count1 < maxFields) {
                        comboLbl = new JLabel("Select a relation:");
                        fruits[count1] = new JComboBox<String>(fruitOptions1);
                        MyItemListener2 actionListener2 = new MyItemListener2(count1);
                        fruits[count1].addItemListener(actionListener2);
                        // System.out.println("HI: " + fruits[count1].getParent());
                        dude2[count1] = new JComboBox<String>();
                        System.out.println("ADD FIELDS: " + count1);
                        comboPanel.add(comboLbl);
                        comboPanel.add(fruits[count1]);
                        comboPanel.add(dude2[count1]);
                        guiFrame.validate();
                        guiFrame.repaint();
                        count1++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You reached the maximum of 4 fields.");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        comboPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(comboPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        comboPanel.add(addField);
        // The JFrame uses the BorderLayout layout manager.
        // Put the two JPanels and JButton in different areas.
        guiFrame.add(comboPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        // make sure the JFrame is visible
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyItemListener2 implements ItemListener {
        private int index;

        public MyItemListener2(int pIndex) {
            super();
            index = pIndex;
        }

        // This method is called only if a new item has been selected.
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {

            if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                // Item was just selected
                System.out.println("COUNTER: " + index);
                System.out.println(evt.getItem());

                dude2[index].removeAllItems();
                switch ((String) evt.getItem()) {
                case "Delay1":
                    for (int i = 0; i < valOptions1.length; i++) {
                        dude2[index].addItem(valOptions1[i]); // dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                        System.out.println(valOptions1[i]);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Delay2": 
                    for (int j = 0; j < valOptions2.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println(valOptions2[j]);
                        dude2[index].addItem(valOptions2[j]); // dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                    }
                    break;
                case "Delay3":
                    for (int j = 0; j < valOptions3.length; j++) {
                        System.out.println(valOptions3[j]);
                        dude2[index].addItem(valOptions3[j]); // dude1 = new JComboBox(valOptions1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I think this solves your request. I removed any unused code but kept all variablenames. Please chose the names for your variables in a way anyone reading the code knows what the variable is for.

It is pretty obvious you do not know java or any other high programming language. I'd recommend you to learn the basics first before trying to programm fancy stuff.

I hope this helps you